# Off Screen Rendering

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

In off screen rendering in metal

```
let textureDescriptors = MTLTextureDescriptor()
textureDescriptors.textureType = MTLTextureType.type2D
let screenRatio = UIScreen.main.scale
textureDescriptors.width = Int((DrawingManager.shared.size?.width)!) * Int(screenRatio)
textureDescriptors.height = Int((DrawingManager.shared.size?.height)!) * Int(screenRatio)
textureDescriptors.pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
textureDescriptors.storageMode = .shared
textureDescriptors.usage = [.renderTarget, .shaderRead]
ssTexture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDescriptors)
ssTexture.label = "ssTexture"
```

Here the texture is in Clear color. Is it possible to load a image texture and is it posible to render the image texture in Draw Method

```
let renderPass = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
renderPass.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
renderPass.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0)
renderPass.colorAttachments[0].texture = ssTexture
renderPass.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .store
```

Comment: Here I need to pass a RGB texture for rendering. I need to make the changes to that texture. Like In some places I want to make transparent. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking.

- There's `MTLTextureLoader` for creating textures initialized with the contents of an image.
- You can use the `replace(region:...)` methods of `MTLTexture` to fill all or part of a texture with image data.
- You can use `MTLBlitCommandEncoder` to copy data from one texture to (all or part of) another or from a buffer to a texture.
- You can draw to a texture or write to it from a compute shader.

It's a general-purpose API. There are many ways to do the things you seem to be asking. What have you tried? In what way did those attempts fail to achieve what you want?

Comment: Is it possible to make changes in Texture in Fragment Shader by passing texture to Fragment Shader

Comment: In compute Shader we can do it. I want to know whether can we do it in using fragment shader

Comment: On some versions of iOS, with some GPU families, yes fragment shaders can write to textures. See the [Metal Feature Set Tables](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables.pdf) (PDF). Look for the row labeled "Function texture read-writes". Also, a fragment shader is drawing to a texture, which is a form of writing and can achieve what you want. Why is drawing not enough for what you want to do?